# Unused Bean Get Called in Spring App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some strange behavior in my Spring App, here is my Java Spring Boot application structure:

in package `com.somethingsomething.packageA`, **I have 2 files**

**First** is `ParentA.java`

```
package com.somethingsomething.packageA;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ParentA {
    @Autowired
    private ChildA childA;

    public ChildA getChildA() {
        return childA;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void ParentAPostConstruct() {
        System.out.println("ParentA PostConstruct were called");
    }
}
```

**Second** is `ChildA.java`

```
package com.somethingsomething.packageA;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ChildA {
    public ChildA() {
        System.out.println("ChildA were called");
    }
}
```

and then under package `com.somethingsomething.packageB`, **I also** have two similar files.

**First** is `ParentB.java`

```
package com.somethingsomething.packageB;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ParentB {
    @Autowired
    private ChildB childB;

    public ChildB getChildB() {
        return childB;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void ParentBPostConstruct() {
        System.out.println("ParentB PostConstruct were called");
    }
}
```

**Second** is `ChildB.java`

```
package com.somethingsomething.packageB;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ChildB {
    public ChildB() {
        System.out.println("ChildB were called");
    }
}
```

Both of `packageA` and `packageB` have similar structure. **Then** under `com.somethingsomething` I have two main function for both package:

`ForPackageA.java`

```
package com.somethingsomething;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.somethingsomething.packageA.ParentA;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ForPackageA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext =
                SpringApplication.run(ForPackageA.class, args);

        ParentA parentA =
                applicationContext.getBean(ParentA.class);

        System.out.println(parentA);
        System.out.println(parentA.getChildA());        
    }
}
```

and `ForPackageB.java`

```
package com.somethingsomething;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.somethingsomething.packageB.ParentB;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ForPackageB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext =
                SpringApplication.run(ForPackageB.class, args);

        ParentB parentB =
                applicationContext.getBean(ParentB.class);

        System.out.println(parentB);
        System.out.println(parentB.getChildB());        
    }
}
```

When i run `ForPackageA.java`, this will appear in log:

```
ChildA were called
ParentA PostConstruct were called
ChildB were called
ParentB PostConstruct were called
com.somethingsomething.packageA.ParentA@88d6f9b
com.somethingsomething.packageA.ChildA@47d93e0d
```

The `ChildB were called` and `ParentB PostConstruct were called` were not suppose to be there, since `ForPackageA.java` doesn't depend on those beans. **Why is this happening?**

The same thing also happening when i run `ForPackageB.java`, which will log following:

```
ChildA were called
ParentA PostConstruct were called
ChildB were called
ParentB PostConstruct were called
com.somethingsomething.packageB.ParentB@610db97e
com.somethingsomething.packageB.ChildB@6f0628de
```

But in this case `ChildA were called` and `ParentA PostConstruct were called` were not suppose to be logged.

So, why is this peculiar behavior is happening? **Is this default behavior of Spring?**

> Edit:
>
> If let say i add following line
>   `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` to `ParentB.java`
>   (after `@Component`)
>
> It will not make `ParentB PostConstruct were called` appear when i run
>   `ForPackageA.java`.
>
> and also, if i add those line to `ChildB.java` it will **also** not
>   make `ChildB were called` appear when i run `ForPackageA.java`
>
> Why are the beans act **differently** in **prototype** mode, i.e. they are **not getting called** like when they are in **singleton** mode?

Comment: Note that a class annotated `@SpringBootApplication` is implicitly annotated `@ComponentScan` , and the scan starts from the current package to all sub-packages .Try putting `ForPackageA` in `packageA` and `ForPackageB` in `packageB`

Comment: I know if i implicitly annotated `@ComponentScan` it will resolve those unnecessary Bean calls, but it is kind of strange that all beans get initialized even though it's not called or used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, this is default behaviour of Spring. At application start all Beans with a `@Component` annotation get created, no matter if you use them or not.

The call `applicationContext.getBean(ParentB.class)` then simply returns the already created Bean.

*To answer your edit:*
Spring Beans are by default Singletons, so theres always only one instance of the bean per `applicationContext`. This is *Inversion of Control*, meaning that Spring handles object instantiation, not you.

Beans with the Prototype scope can have multiple object instances and can, in a way, be instantiated by you. (By calling `applicationContext.getBean(ParentA.class)`). This is similar to doing something like `ParentA a = new ParentA()`.

I suggest you read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes) to get a deeper understanding of scopes.

Answer (score 1):

The bean object creation doesn't depends on which object you are trying to get. Whenever spring application gets launched, its all components object are created automatically and you are getting already created component object using `applicationContext.getBean(componentClass)` method. Hope this will help you to understand why you are getting logs for every object.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this happening?

When you start your Spring app the `ApplicationContext` is initialised by component scanning your application and registering all Spring annotated beans in the context.  This allows them to be injected as required.

> Is this default behaviour of Spring?

Yes.  You can change this behaviour by configuring the component scanning to only look at specified packages if you wish (although the use cases for this are few and far between).